# Windows: Have a new user to utilize another user profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, users, profile

This is a bit tricky and hope you can help me. I'm migrating from an old domain to a new one lots of Windows Servers, now I'm in a point where some years ago somebody set up two VMs (Win 2k3) to run a specific software. Now, that sofware only allows you to run and edit its configuration from a single account, guess what account they've chose? The Domain Administrator account.

So basically I can't migrate the account.

What I want to do is create a local account, now the question, is there a way to link this local account to the Administrator profile on those machines? So basically I want to link the local account to the Domain Admin account.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I've just tried it locally on a test VM and it worked as expected... I'll try to get the VHDs and give it a try on a test server.

Comment: I'm restoring the VHDs now to a different location, then I'll configure a test VM in a test VM host and let you know. Cheers!

Comment: Mark it as an answer :) I managed to access the domain\admin profile with a brand new local account. Now it's time for some reverse engineering on that software :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Forensit's profile wizard, I've used it plenty but not in this situation.  Should work fine for you though.

See here for the free software:  http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html

More info on the product here: http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html